# Using ngCsv with an external API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

So I have an external API which I'm trying to access and extract the data in it using JSONP and $resource service. I want to have a button from [ngCsv](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv) which makes the request then when the data request completed exports the array to a csv file. but when I click the button it saves an empty csv file because the request takes about 11s to complete. I want to click the button and when the data was ready and received completely, export the csv file.

Here's my app.js

```js
// Initializing Application
angular.module('angelApp',['ngRoute','ngResource','ngSanitize','ngCsv'])

.config(function ($locationProvider,$routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider
  .html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase:false
  })
  .hashPrefix('!');
  $routeProvider
  .when('/',{
    templateUrl: 'displays/main.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })
  .when('/extract',{
    templateUrl: 'displays/extract.html',
    controller: 'extractController'
  })
  .when('/about',{
    templateUrl: 'displays/about.html',
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
})

// Defining Controllers
// Main page Controller
.controller('mainController',['$scope',function ($scope) {
  $scope.home = "Home Page!"
}])

// Extract Page Controller
.controller('extractController',['$scope','apiExtractService',function ($scope,apiExtractService) {
  $scope.extract = function () {
    return extractedData = apiExtractService.apiExtract();
  }
}])

// Adding Services To the application
.service('apiExtractService',['$resource',function ($resource) {
  this.apiExtract = function () {
    var apiData = $resource("APIADDRESS",{callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"},{get:{method: "JSONP"}});
    return apiData.get({filter: "FILTER",access_token:"TOKEN"});
  }
}])
```

Here's my extract.html route.

```html
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <button type="button" ng-csv="extract()" filename="test.csv">Export</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using $resource which returns a promise. So you need to catch the return value and return to your controller function as below

```
// Extract Page Controller
 .controller('extractController',['$scope','apiExtractService',function ($scope,apiExtractService) {

     $scope.extract = function () {
       return apiExtractService.apiExtract().then(function(results){
               return results;
             });
     }

  }])
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
Someone basically said the same thing before me, but I'll leave this here just in case it helps anyone :)

When you want to take action after your request has been resolved, it's a perfect case to use promises.
Make your `apiExtractService.apiExtract` method return a promise and take advantage of it. For example:

```
function apiExtract(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http("get", "sampleUrl", optionalData)
        .success(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        })
        .error(function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

and in your controller:

```
.controller('extractController',['$scope','apiExtractService',function ($scope,apiExtractService) {
  $scope.extract = function () {
    apiExtractService.apiExtract()
    .then(function(response){
     return response;
     }, function(err){
     console.log("something went wrong");
     });
  }
```

Comment: $resource already uses promises! No need to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Where should I add function apiExtract() ? Inside my Service?

Comment: Yes apiExtract was meant as an example function that returns a promise. the $resource feature you use already uses a promise as @NickNasirpour mentioned which means you can keep using that, the $http service I used is not needed, it's just I'm used to it and never used $resource so I provided the example with something I was more comfortable with :)

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a $resource in the apiExtract function, which uses promises. Instead of returning the promise to the extract function, you should return the actual content, which can be done using angularJS's $resource.$promise attribute.

```
$scope.extract = function() {
    apiExtractService.apiExtract().$promise.then(function(extractedData){
        return extractedData;
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, but somehow it doesn't work! I don't know why! I'm using angular v1.4.8! what do you think?

Comment: Can you show me what your apiExtract function is returning?

Comment: Yep, the JSON the API should be returning

Answer (score 1):

I too had same issue. I was getting an empty file even after using a promise. I was able to resolve it by passing in the Array instead of entire API response JSON.

API response was

```
{
    "responseStatus": "001",
        "orderList":
    [{
        "id": 33, "status": null, "lastUpdatedDate": null, "lastUpdatedUser": null,
        "orderId": 1469830, "amount": 96, "discount": 6, "isPaid": "Y"
    }]
}
```

In the controller

```
    .controller('extractController', ['$scope', 'apiExtractService', function ($scope, apiExtractService) {
    $scope.extract = function () {
        apiExtractService.apiExtract()
            .then(function (response) {
                //You have to return an array not full JSON
                return response.orderList;
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("something went wrong");
            });
    }
}
```