# AngularJS: Empty CSV file when using ngCsv

Tags: angularjs, csv

I am using ngCsv to try and export data to CSV. After clicking a button, I download all required data after which I would like to export it to CSV. However, I am getting a blank CSV for some reason. Below is the code for the button:

```
<button class="btn-primary" type="button" ng-csv="getAllData()" csv-header="['Order Number', 'Handling Code', 'Expected Date', 'Status', 'Reference', 'Loading Date', 'Unloading Date', 'Transaction Status']" filename="test.csv">Export to CSV</button>
```

The method I use to download the data:

```
$scope.getAllData = function () {
            return ordersService.getAllOrders()
                .success(function (data) {                        
                    return data.Items;
                })
        };
```

The getAllOrders method:

```
service.getAllOrders = function () {
    return $http.get(ordersApiBase);
};
```

I've tried varoius other ways as can be seen here:
[Using ngCsv with an external API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554607/using-ngcsv-with-an-external-api)
and here:
https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv/issues/58 yet I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Has anyone done something similar before?

Comment: Might be the problem with the return data. Can you `console.log(data.Items)`? And post the result?

Comment: I have checked this and it returns the full list of objects:

`, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object…]
[0 … 99]
0: Object
ExpectedDate: "12/3/2015 12:00:00 AM"
HandlingCode: "i"
OrderNumber: "8500000007193"
Reference: "PO-106993"`

Comment: Currently, `ng-csv` is not supporting nested objects.